# Making a custom Log category in Windows 7, C#

Tags: c#, .net

Just wondering make a Log category in Windows 7, I got it on XP but a bit confusing in Windows 7, any idea?

```
if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("MyReminderService"))
    EventLog.CreateEventSource("MyReminderService", "MyReminderServiceLog");

 EventLog log = new EventLog("MyReminderServiceLog");
 log.Source = "MyReminderServiceLog";
 log.WriteEntry("The Exeption message...");
```

Answer (score 2):

It's the same for both Windows XP and Windows 7. The reason it might not work on Windows 7 out of the box is because you will probably need administrator access (which you have by default in Windows XP) to create the Event Log source.

Run your application as an administrator and it'll probably work.